# Get only changed values at postback from EditorFor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, editorfor

I have a list of objects that I am displaying in a View using EditorFor. User can change the values of the objects. At postback I want to get only the list of objects modified, not entire list. How can I do that? thank you

Comment: If you have created controls for the list they will all post back (unless they are disabled). You could get the original list from the database and compare them.

Comment: yes, that is my solution at the moment.. comparing with the original value.. but I was wondering if there isn't an easier way maybe from mvc to somehow filter the information from editorFor if it's value was change

Comment: Not MVC but you could add a `IsDirty` property to your view model and use javascipt/jquery to update the value when any of the corresponding property controls are changed.

Comment: so with js I need to mark IsDirty true when this is changed from UI before postback. Can you please point me to an example of how this can be done?

Comment: Ensure your controls for each item are rendered in a container (if its a table, then the `<tr>` element would be the container). Use event delegation (jquery `.on()`) to handle the `change` or `blur` event of all controls. In that function, get all the controls associated with the item (i.e. in the associated container) and compare their `value` and `defaultValue` (or `defaultChecked`). If they are different, set the hidden input value to `true` and exit the loop. Have a go, and if your having problems, post the code and the html.

Comment: I need some help please. In my view I have:

Comment: I need some help please. In my view I have:
<div id="Values"> @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Values)      </div>    
In my editor template I have 
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.SassValue, new{ @onchange= "@{Model.IsValueChanged = true" })
When I inspect the page after load all values for IsValueChanged are false, which is correct. When I get to the 
controller (even if I don't change any values),IsValueChanged for all objects are true.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In that textbox I am using jscolor so the user can select a new color, and i believe that raises the onchange event at load. Do you have any other thoughts on this?